# How to listen to changes in background (Parse Server)

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, backend, parse-cloud-code

The task I want to accomplish is the following: Change some fields in the Parse dashboard and make the app respond right after. So pretty much make the UI respond to a change in the server.

After searching for a while, I see that I should set it up through Parse Cloud Code and use methods like `afterSave`. But as of now, I understand how to listen to an object being saved. How should I manage to do it the opposite way, which is the app listen to a change in the server? I will be manually changing some variables in the Parse Dashboard and I want the user to be able to get it whenever I manually change it.  I could set up a timer (as a method inside the app’s code) and check it from the server in a 5 seconds interval but that would be pretty much inefficient in terms of requests, internet data.

Comment: You need to send a silent push notification to the relevant device(s) in the `afterSave` code

Comment: @Paulw11, How? Where (inside which function?) should I put the `PFCloud` code in the `ViewController`?

Comment: The `afterSave` function is on your server; then any update to the record will trigger it, regardless of where that change was made.

Answer (score 1):

You have few solution choice.
I dont know your architecture and your technologies what you use but I wrote two solutions.

1. silent notification with push server:
   You need a push server on backend and you can send a silent push to frontend when the afterSave code triggering. However frontend code should be subscribe your push server.
   e.g.: https://justmarkup.com/log/2017/02/implementing-push-notifications/
2. websocket communication:
   You need a socket server on backend and a socket client on frontend and if you have a channel then you can send a message to client from server.
   e.g.: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/

I hope It will be help you.